# What is included in MS WebPI's Recommended Server Configuration for Web Hosting Providers

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-7.5, web-platform-installer

Microsoft's Web Platform Installer includes an item titled:

**Recommended Server Configuration for Web Hosting Providers**

This sounds handy, but I'm not about to install it without knowing what sort of configuration changes it makes. Could someone explain or provide a link to what bits this flips? My google-fu is usually strong, but I've not been able to find much about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It installs the following components:

- .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and 4
- IIS 7 or 7.5
- ASP.NET MVC version 1, 2 and 3
- Web Deployment Tool 2.1
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client, Management Objects, and CLR Types  (but not the server product itself)
- PHP 5.2.17
- PHP Manager for IIS
- MySQL Connector for .NET
- MSSQL driver for PHP

It also enables a number of IIS features such as:

- Tracing
- URL Rewrite
- CGI
- FTP Server
- Management Service

Comment: Where did you find this information?

Comment: In WebPI itself -- all you have to do is ask it to install something and it will show you all the products and features that will be installed along with it.